# PEMParser hanging with no exception thrown

Tags: java, encryption, mule, bouncycastle, pem

I have a String variable that contains a test Private key, when outputting the key string, it looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,BD15DCECA635FDE0

[Encrypted-Key-Contents]

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I've checked on my ubuntu system and the key is valid and working. However, when I try to run PEMParser on it, it just hangs and I get no exception thrown. Here is what I do in order to parse it:

```
System.out.println(myKey);  // this outputs the key just fine.
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
InputStream keyInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(myKey.getBytes());
InputStreamReader in2 = new InputStreamReader(keyInput);
PEMParser parserPrivateKey = new PEMParser(in2);
```

Everything appears to work fine until the line that creates a PEMParser runs. None of my code after this runs, yet I do not get any exception from this when using my application (Which is in Mule.)

Am I missing something here? Why would there be a problem with creating an instance of PEMParser from this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert, but what you are showing does not look like a key in PEM format.

Compare with: http://www.herongyang.com/Cryptography/Certificate-Format-PEM-on-Certificates.html

This may help: https://sycure.wordpress.com/2008/05/15/tips-using-openssl-to-extract-private-key-pem-file-from-pfx-personal-information-exchange/